# How can I draw an ellipse using QPainter?

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I want to draw ellipse in UI but my code doesn't work.

```
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
```

**mainwindow.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
 : QMainWindow(parent)
 , ui(new Ui::MainWindow), pm(100,100)
{
 ui->setupUi(this);
 //set_form_style();
 draw_ellipse();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
 delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::set_form_style(){
 //setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
 //setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
 //ui->widget->setStyleSheet("background:transparent;");

 setMouseTracking(true);

}

void MainWindow::draw_ellipse(){
 QPainter painter(this);
 painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
 painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::red, Qt::SolidPattern));
 painter.drawEllipse(100, 50, 150, 150);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue isn't the way you're using the `QPainter`, it's the time you're obtaining it.

As the [reference documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#details) says, "the common use of QPainter is inside a widget's paint event". So if you want to do custom painting in your main window, override `paintEvent` and put your code there.